# Vectorised column operations in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am looking for a tidy way of incorporating vectorised operations on columns using dplyr.

Basically, having a simple df as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame("X" = runif(1:10), 
             "Y" = runif(1:10), "Z" = runif(1:10)) %>% 
 tbl_df()
```

I am now looking to apply the following vectorised formula:

```
Formula <- "X / Y + lag(Z)"
```

Of course the following won't work as it is looking for a column 'X / Y + lag(Z)':

```
df %>% mutate(Result := !!sym(Formula))
```

Can anyone suggest a simple way of applying a formula from a vector directly in a pipe on columns to achieve:

```
df %>% mutate(Result = X/Y+lag(Z))
```

Comment: @Ronak Shah, apologies- adjustment made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame("X" = runif(1:10), 
                 "Y" = runif(1:10), "Z" = runif(1:10)) %>% 
    tbl_df()

Formula <- "X / Y + lag(Z)"

df <- df %>% mutate(Result = eval(parse(text = Formula)))

        X      Y      Z Result
    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 0.153  0.0158 0.527  NA    
 2 0.322  0.231  0.327   1.93 
 3 0.479  0.0958 0.365   5.33 
 4 0.764  0.537  0.105   1.79 
 5 0.180  0.223  0.0243  0.913
 6 0.178  0.538  0.975   0.355
 7 0.869  0.820  0.845   2.03 
 8 0.356  0.263  0.0628  2.20 
 9 0.0399 0.710  0.968   0.119
10 0.863  0.422  0.825   3.02
```

`parse` an unevaluated expression, then `eval`uate it.

Comment: Of course that's the one thanks... Was overthinking it - your solution is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, `parse_expr` can be used

```
library(dplyr)    
df <- df %>% 
         mutate(Calc_Col = !! rlang::parse_expr(Formula))
```

and if we need to pass the column name as variable, use the `:=` (as @Nick mentioned in the comments)

```
Name <- "Calc_Col" 
df <- df %>% 
        mutate(!!Name := !!rlang::parse_expr(Formula))
```

Comment: To parameterise the column name too: Name <- "Calc_Col" ;Formula <- "X / Y + lag(Z)";
df <- df %>% mutate(!!Name := !!rlang::parse_expr(Formula))